# How do I send data via post where it call route through controller laravel?

Tags: laravel, redirect, post, routes, laravel-5.3

My case like this :

I have add method. If the method run, it will call route

The code like this :

```
public function add(Request $request)
{
    ...
    return redirect('shop/payment/checkout/'.json_encode($data['cart']).'/'.$id);
}
```

My route like this :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'shop','as'=>'shop.'], function () {
    Route::get('payment/checkout/{cart}/{id}', ['as'=>'payment.checkout','uses'=>'ShopController@checkout']);
});
```

It will call checkout method in the shop controller

The method like this :

```
public function checkout($cart=null, $id=null)
{
    dd($cart, $id)
}
```

It works

If the code execute, it will display the result of `$cart` and `$id`

But it use `get`

I want to change it use `post`

Because if use `get` the data cart look in the url

How can I solve this problem?

So the data not visible in the url

Seems this case must use `post`

But I'm still confused use `post` in this case

Answer (score 1):

You can't redirect with POST, that's an http limitation, not Laravel.

Maybe the neatest solution is to [flash the data you need to the session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data):

Controller:

```php
public function add(Request $request)
{
    ...
    return redirect('shop/payment/checkout')->with('cart', json_encode($data['cart'])->with('id', $id);
}
```

Route:

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'shop','as'=>'shop.'], function () {
    Route::get('payment/checkout', ['as'=>'payment.checkout','uses'=>'ShopController@checkout']);
});
```

Controller:

```php
public function checkout()
{
    dd(session($cart), session($id))
}
```